# How to get to the GRUB in ASUS Zenbook?

Tags: grub2

I am trying to access the GRUB from my ubuntu installation as shown here: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

But I get the following result. How can I get to the GRUB? Any Idea?
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJD9m.jpg)

Adding the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: The screenshot is not from inside an Ubuntu installation. It is, apparently, a BIOS boot manager. Let Ubuntu boot, and then make the changes, as outlined in the linked question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My problem is actually a little bit more complicated. I am trying to install Ubuntuon ASUS Zenbook, but after the installation I got a blank screen: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/a3ddg6/anyone_installed_linux_on_a_asus_zenbook_pro_1415/

Comment: You should have posted your whole problem not just a part.

Answer (score 0):

This screenshot shows the boot device selection menu from bios. Once you select the first option, grub is loaded. Press ESC quick and you should be able to access grub.

Comment: No results... apart from the usual blank screen

Comment: I reinstalled on the same machine. Now none of  the methods is working? How should I proceed?

Comment: I definitely managed to access the grub... howevere aftervarious practical attempts.. I think that is a reallybig issuehincering the adoption of Ubunut systems on Asus Zenbooks

Answer (score 0):

Note: The screenshot you attached is bios menu for choosing boot device. Select the first option (Ubuntu) then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to access grub menu.

Here is what I did to make changes permanent.
Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then replace

`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`

with

`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`

EDIT: If the above line does not exist then add it.

And make sure `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is not set to 0.

Then run `sudo update-grub` and then restart you should see grub menu everytime you power on your notebook. To undo the changes replace the file with original contents and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: line "GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden" is not present in my grub file

Comment: @giulio You probably have older Ubuntu version. I am using 18.10 and I am pretty sure that this line exist in 18.04, 17.04 too. Search for line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` if it doesn't exist then do `cat /etc/default/grub` and post the output

Comment: Dear Saurav, I am using the 19.04..

Comment: You'll find the output in the main question text

Comment: @giulio Could you add output of `cat /etc/default/grub` to your question?

Comment: It is added, see above

Comment: @giulio add the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` in your grub config file and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` then `sudo update-grub` and reboot to see if grub is visible.